# Google Autocomplete API - format output result

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-places-api, jquery-events

I'm trying to implement Google Places API, so here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places&location=0,0&radius=20000000&language=de"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var el = $('#street').attr("placeholder", "")
                    , autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( ( el.get(0) ), { types: ['geocode'] } );

            el.bind("blur", function() {
                // blur is triggered before place_changed, as well as focus... so this is not working as well
            })

            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

                el.val(place.name); // this line is not working well - still default content showing !!!
            });
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body">
    <input type="text" id="street" style="width:400px;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Google Autocomplete works fine, however I have one of requirements - only show street name & number instead of full address suggested by Google. So I can get all information by running `autocomplete.getPlace()` at "place_changed" event - there are no problems with that.

The problem is that I can't override autocomplete input value with my custom text - I've tried to do it within "blur", "focus", "place_changed" events - still no luck. Please find an example of what I was trying. Also - I need to avoid text flashing, to make it absolutely user-friendly. Could someone help me with my attempts?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8pGH2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var el = $('#street').attr("placeholder", "")
        , autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete( ( el.get(0) ), { types: ['geocode'] } );

        el.bind("blur", function() {
          el.css("color", "#fff"); // this will prevent text flashing
        })

        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
           var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

            el.val(place.name);

            // this will override default Google suggestion
            setTimeout(function() {
                el.val(place.name);
                el.css("color", "");
            }, 0)
        });
})
```

Comment: hi there, thanks for this solutions, the problem with this is if you focus in the input and blur without selection any place, the text color will stay as white, any thought to improve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can get by

```
el.get(0).getLocality()
```

Comment: get street name & number is not a problem - the problem where to put this code?

Comment: el.get(0) at that replace el.get(0).getLocality()

Comment: ok thank you for this code - it works, but the text is flashing - you can check it on fiddle. So I need something more than that.

Comment: but in fiddle i'm getting fine...,,how your getting after some the address is getting  in the drop down

Comment: could you give me a link to Fiddle please? I can't get what you mean. If I try your code I'm seeing Google Suggestion text, and then it replaces with street name & number. But the goal is to prevent text flashing.